# Inserting a table in a database without knowing prefix

Tags: mysql

I have a small script that will insert two tables in a database, which works fine unless the user has changed the default prefix. I am wondering how I can call and use the "prefix" from the config file. Here is my code.

```html
<?php

include("../../Config/config.php");

$link = mysql_connect($CONFIG['host'], $CONFIG['login'], $CONFIG['password'];
$db = ($CONFIG['database']);

if (!$link)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

$db_selected = mysql_select_db("$db", $link);

$sql = 'INSERT INTO settings '.
          '(id, field, value) '.
          'VALUES ("NULL", "show_thumbs_down", "1")';

$exec = mysql_query($sql, $link); 
if (!$exec) die(mysql_error());

mysql_close($link);

?>
```

You can see that I call "config.php" to get the database info. That would also work to get the prefix but I'm not sure how to implement the "prefix" with the rest of the code.

FYI: I'm a newbie :)

Thanks.

Comment: Try clarifying what you mean

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear. My script will install a value into a table, "settings" in my example  above with no issue, as long as my table doesn't have a prefix. I installed my main cript again and added the prefix "rj4848g_" to my tables and now my script wont work saying "site.settings does not exist" "site being the name of the database and "settings" being the name of the table I want modified. it should be looking for site rj4848g_settings. How do I make it so my scripts find the table prefix and adds it accordingly?

Comment: I meant in the questions; the question's the first impression. I actually have no interest in answering this question, I was reviewing it and left you a comment to help you learn this site.

Comment: If you have no interest in helping then please don't waste my time.

Comment: I think you misunderstood - I want to help you to get a warm reception on this site; however, that doesn't neccessarily mean I want to answer your question. That's what review queues are for!

Answer (score 1):

I got it, here's what worked.

```
<?php

require_once ("../../Config/config.php");

$link = mysql_connect($CONFIG['host'], $CONFIG['login'],$CONFIG['password']);
$table_prefix = ($CONFIG['prefix']);
$db = ($CONFIG['database']);


if (!$link)
{
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

$db_selected = mysql_select_db("$db", $link);

$sql = 'INSERT INTO ' . $table_prefix . 'settings'.
'(id, field, value) '.
'VALUES ("NULL", "show_thumbs_down", "1")';

$exec = mysql_query($sql, $link);
if (!$exec) die(mysql_error());

mysql_close($link);

?>
```

Thanks for the help BK435

Answer (score 0):

Welcome!

I am assuming you can get the prefix and store it in variable.  When calling your sql add this  to your code ' . $TABLE_PREFIX . '. so your above insert would look something like:

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO ' . $TABLE_PREFIX . 'settings '.
          '(id, field, value) '.
          'VALUES ("NULL", "show_thumbs_down", "1")';
```

Comment: here is the code I have now, with your suggestion added. however its still not working. `<?php

include("../../Config/config.php");

$link = mysql_connect($CONFIG['host'], $CONFIG['login'], $CONFIG['password']);
$prefix = ($CONFIG['prefix']);
$db = ($CONFIG['database']);


if (!$link)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

$db_selected = mysql_select_db("$db", $link);

$sql = 'INSERT INTO " . $prefix . " settings'.
          '(id, field, value) '.
          'VALUES ("NULL", "show_thumbs_down", "1")';

$exec = mysql_query($sql, $link);
if (!$exec) die(mysql_error());`